# Error publishing ASP.NET Core project

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core RC1 project that no longer publishes correctly (see publish trace output, below). The `gulp min` task in the prepublish script defined in `project.json` is causing the error. If I remove it, the project publishes correctly, but without minifying the js and css files.

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
}
```

I have added another Web Project to the solution, and that publishes without error, so I think that eliminates environmental issues. However, I can't see anything substantially different between the test project and the one that fails.

I have also deleted the `node_modules` folder in the failing project to force Visual Studio to download all the npm packages again.

Finally I ran the `dnu publish` command in the trace below from the VS command prompt and that also failed.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is from the error trace below, please?

```
Connecting to C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\..\..\artifacts\bin\xxx.Web\Release\PublishOutput...
Environment variables:
Path=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
C:\Users\ptayl_000\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final\bin\dnu.cmd publish "C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb" --out "C:\Users\ptayl_000\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\xxx.Web104" --configuration Release --no-source --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final --wwwroot "wwwroot" --wwwroot-out "wwwroot" --iis-command "web" --quiet
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16202
Executing script 'prepublish' in project.json
v0.10.31
npm WARN package.json ASP.NET@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json ASP.NET@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ASP.NET@0.0.0 No README data
[07:36:31] Using gulpfile C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\gulpfile.js
[07:36:31] Starting 'clean:js'...
[07:36:31] Starting 'clean:css'...
[07:36:31] Finished 'clean:js' after 1.68 ms
[07:36:31] Finished 'clean:css' after 1.99 ms
[07:36:31] Starting 'clean'...
[07:36:31] Finished 'clean' after 9.03 μs
[07:36:32] Using gulpfile C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\gulpfile.js
[07:36:32] Starting 'min:js'...
[07:36:32] Starting 'min:css'...
[07:36:32] Finished 'min:css' after 61 ms
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error : events.js:72
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :               ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error : Error
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at new JS_Parse_Error (C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:196:18)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at js_error (C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:204:11)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at croak (C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:675:9)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at token_error (C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:683:9)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at expect_token (C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:696:9)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at expect (C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:699:36)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:1252:13
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:722:24
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at expr_atom (C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:1182:35)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at maybe_unary (C:\svn\Client Applications\yyy\xxx\src\xxxWeb\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:1358:19)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error : The 'prepublish' script failed with status code 8.

2>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
```

**Update**
The `gulp min` task contains the following code (from `gulp.js`):

```
gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

**Update2: event.js**

```
var rx = require("rx");

function normalizeKeypressEvents(args) {
  return { value: args[0], key: args[1] };
}

module.exports = function(rl) {
  return {
    line: rx.Observable.fromEvent(rl, "line"),

    keypress: rx.Observable.fromEvent(rl, "keypress", normalizeKeypressEvents),

    normalizedUpKey: rx.Observable.fromEvent(rl, "keypress", normalizeKeypressEvents).filter(function (e) {
      return e.key && (e.key.name === "up" || e.key.name === "k");
    }).share(),

    normalizedDownKey: rx.Observable.fromEvent(rl, "keypress", normalizeKeypressEvents).filter(function (e) {
      return e.key && (e.key.name === "down" || e.key.name === "j");
    }).share(),

    numberKey: rx.Observable.fromEvent(rl, "keypress", normalizeKeypressEvents).filter(function (e) {
      return e.value && "123456789".indexOf(e.value) >= 0;
    }).map(function(e) {
      return Number(e.value);
    }).share(),

    spaceKey: rx.Observable.fromEvent(rl, "keypress", normalizeKeypressEvents).filter(function (e) {
      return e.key && e.key.name === "space";
    }).share(),

  };
};
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the Error List tab?

Comment: The same as the ones starting with "c:\Program Files ..." in the trace above.

Comment: Could you post the content of your gulp min task?

Comment: It is an error on minifying the JavaScripts. Do you have some custom JavaScripts. Maybe it is an error because some missing braces or something like this your JavaScript file.

Comment: @JuergenGutsch, I have checked the .js files and no syntax errors are being flagged. They are working correctly as well.

Comment: @janpieter_z gulp task added to the question.

Comment: What does running the gulp task directly tell you? And could you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003457/gulp-uglify-events-js-unhandled-error-event

Comment: How can I run the gulp task directly (sorry, I'm new to npm)?

Comment: could you please post the events.js somewhere e.g. gist? the parser doesn't like the part on line 72

Comment: The only events.js on my pc is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\bower\node_modules\inquirer\lib\utils\events.js and it has only 32 lines! Posted as an update to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that it was a piece of application javascript that was causing the "gulp min" task to fail. The culprit was the following seemingly innocuous piece of code:

```
$http.get(uri, { params: { config } }).then(function (data) {
    return data;
});
```

I still can't see any problem with it, but as the code had become redundant, I removed it and solved the problem that way.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issues (even on the same line numbers). Paul's own answer gave me a clue to look carefully at my own .js

I commented out most of the file and then progressively uncommented blocks of code until the errors came back.

And the offending code?
This line that uses a template string was the problem:

```
rtUl.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<li>${el.toString()}</li>`);
```

Changing it back to a simple concatenation worked:

```
rtUl.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<li>" + el.toString() + "</li>");
```

It seems that uglify can't read string templates (yet).